# Cómo obtener los registros en mi relación ManyToMany con Django

Tags: django

Tengo dos modelos llamados `Mascota` y `Vacuna`. Deseo ver los registros en mi relación `ManyToMany` tanto para las vacunas que se relacionan con una mascota, como para las mascotas que se relacionan con una vacuna.

En la interfaz interactiva de Django hago algo como ésto:

```
>>> from apps.mascota.models import Mascota, Vacuna
```

Para obtener las vacunas que se le han aplicado a una mascota determinada

```
>>> mascota = Mascota.objects.get(id=#)
>>> vacunas_mascota = mascota.vacunas.all()
```

Lo que necesito es poder obtener las mascotas a las que se le ha aplicado una vacuna determinada. Cuando intento aplicar ésta estrategia no funciona porque como es claro no hay atributo llamado mascota dentro del modelo Vacuna.

Modelo Mascota:

```
class Mascota(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    edad_aproximada = models.IntegerField()
    fecha_rescate = models.DateField()
    raza = models.ForeignKey(Raza, null=False, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vacuna = models.ManyToManyField(Vacuna, blank=True)
```

Modelo Vacuna:

```
class Vacuna(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion = models.TextField(null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

He seguido buscando para resolver mi necesidad en la pregunta anteriormente formulada y en la documentación he encontrado esto: [Relaciones ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships) en donde leyendo y probando con la interfaz interactiva he podido dar con la solución.

En mi ejemplo la solución era:

```
>>>vacuna = Vacuna.objects.get(id=#) 
>>>mascotas_vacuna = vacuna.mascota_set.all()
```